# Submit button not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form and the submit button is not working. Submit is based on whether someone approves or denies. Also approve deny dropdown needs to pre-populate if someone goes back to tha page by using a temp id from what they entered.

It was working when I use html, but when I add in the php it doesn't work. I think it is because I am not calling selectbasic but I don't know where to add the id. I have tried different variations and can't get it to work.

```
  <form name="iform" id="myform" method="post" onsubmit="submitForm" onreset=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="submitForm" class="iform">

      <label for="Email">Email Address for Officer:</label>
      <input class="itext" type="text" value="<?php print $jsonData['Email']; ?>" name="Email" id="Email" />
      <br /><br />

      <label for="ApproveDeny">Approve or Deny Warrant:</label>
      <select class="iselect" name="selectbasic" id="selectbasic">
      <?php
         $values = array("1" => "Choose an option", "2" => "Approved", "3" => "Denied");
         foreach ($values as $value) {
           $selectString = '';
           if ($value == $jsonData['selectbasic']) {
               $selectString = ' selected';
           }
           print '<option value="' . $value . '"' . $selectString . '>' . $value . '</option>';
         }
      ?>                         
      </select>
      <br /><br />

      <label>&nbsp;</label><button type="submit2" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
       <input type="hidden" name="tempId" id="tempId" value="<?php print $tempId; ?>" />

  </form>
```

javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('selectbasic').onchange = function(){

    if (this.value=="2") {
    newAction='html_form_judge.php';
} else if (this.value=="3") {
    newAction='html_form_judgedeny.php';
} else {
    newAction='else.php';
}
     document.getElementById('myform').action = newAction;
   }
       </script>
```

Comment: Show us the HTML *after* the PHP has been processed.

Comment: I presume you have a `submitForm` function? If not, remove `onsubmit="submitForm" onreset=""` --- *Plus*, change `<button type="submit2"` to `<button type="submit"`

Comment: You should handle that logic in php and not change the `action` attribute in javascript based on a form variable.

Comment: Do you really have all those spaces in `class="btn btn-     success"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the value of each option to the name, not numerical key, of each element in your array. Do it like this:

```
foreach ($values as $id => $value) {
    ...
    print '<option value="' . $id . '"' . $selectString . '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

That way, in your javascript, the selected value might actually equal "2" rather than "Approved".

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    ...action="POST"...
for your action attribute. That specifies the type of form submission rather than any function to call prior to sending the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `onrest` from your form element.

If you want form reset functionality, you can add an input with the parameter  `type="reset"`.

I also suggest you rename `submit2` to `submit`.